# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order' - Order is table name

Tags: c#, sql

```
List<Order> results = new List<Order>();

db.Cmd = db.Conn.CreateCommand();
db.Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Order";
db.Rdr = db.Cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (db.Rdr.Read())
{
        results.Add(getOrderFromReader(db.Rdr));
}

db.Rdr.Close();
return results;
```

I get this error when this code runs

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'.'

The result is a list of `Order` objects. The name of the table is `Order` exactly. The method `getOrderFromReader` just takes a row of data from the order table and in puts it into a new order object. I have used this format of code to extract data from all of the tables in the database and the rest works fine but its just the `Order` table that I get this error for, I don't know if this is because of other settings in the database.

Comment: `Order` is a reserved word.  Don't use it for a table name.  Give the table a different name, such as `orders`.

Comment: or put it in square brackets `[Order]`

Answer (score 6):

You will need to put the name of the table in square brackets in order for it to work.

```
List<Order> results = new List<Order>();
db.Cmd = db.Conn.CreateCommand();
db.Cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Order]";
db.Rdr = db.Cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (db.Rdr.Read())
{
        results.Add(getOrderFromReader(db.Rdr));
}
db.Rdr.Close();
return results;
```

**Order** is a SQL reserved word, so you might think about renaming that table, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

`Order` is a keyword in `SQL` used for Ordering/sorting of the resultset.
Here the complier is getting confused with the keyword and your table name.

Solutions :

- Rename your table name
- Enclose your table name in brackets. [Order]. ie, 
  Select * From [Order]